# Jquery Carousel positions sibling below div during fadeIn with strange interactions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

## [FIDDLE code](http://jsfiddle.net/27k9hw6h/6/)

---

#### fadeIn element of carousel appears below visible sibling element

I seem to have a carousel transition issue where the `fadeIn` element of my carousel appears (prematurely?) directly below its visible sibling element (`.active-slide` is used to designate the visible slide ) then quickly takes its place when the transition is finished(the nav arrows at the bottom start the transition).

**Note:**

- This issue only starts after the *second* click function,
  I'm a bit curious why this occurs.
- This issue can be fixed by giving
  `position: absolute;` to `.slide` however this makes the header login
  dropdown `.mouseleave` function run as soon as the cursor moves over
  the `.slide` div. An explanation why the dropdown ends abruptly when this 'fix' is applied would be greatly appreciated as well.

Here is the code used to implement the carousel:

`$('.arrow-next').click(function() {
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();`

```
if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
  nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
}

currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
});
     $('.arrow-prev').click(function() {

var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

  if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
  prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
  }
currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');
  });
```